# Transition in Vue.js is working incorrectly

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, transition

I want to animate `<tr>` when add it dynamically. But it adds  into the . Here's my code.

```
<tbody>   
    <transition-group tag="tr" enter-active-class="animated fadeInUp">       
          <tr v-for="(product, index) in products" v-bind:key="product">                     
            <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
            <td>
              {{ product.price }}
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove control-btn pull-right" @click="removeProduct(index)"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil control-btn pull-right" @click="show(index)"></span>
            </td>                     
          </tr>   
    </transition-group>
    <!-- Итого -->           
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><strong>Итог:</strong> {{ total }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Screenshot of the DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk4Hl.png)

Comment: Just read this issue, I hope it will help you: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3907

Comment: @VitalyMatvievich I'd seen this issue before, but it coudn't help me. Any other ideas? Thank u.

Comment: I think the only way is to change tables to other tags. Look at that one: https://jsfiddle.net/jaco2h22/57/ . Tables do not provide the behavior we need here. That's not what you expect but I think it is the only solution here. I would have change everything to flex layout, for example, if it's possible for you project.

Comment: @VitalyMatvievich I solved the problem

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @VitalyMatvievich I pasted it in the description of my problem.

Comment: Please turn that into an answer, to get this question out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
<transition-group tag="tbody" enter-active-class="animated fadeInUp">                 
    <tr v-for="(product, index) in products" v-bind:key="index">                     
          <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
          <td>
            {{ product.price }}
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove control-btn pull-right" @click="removeProduct(index)"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil control-btn pull-right" @click="show(index)"></span>
          </td>                     
    </tr> 
</transition-group>
```